# Setting FASTLOADCSV Tenacity & Sleep using Teradata jdbc driver

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

Is it possible to set TENACITY & SLEEP for TERADATA FASTLOADCSV calls made via JAVA JDBC?
My jdbc connection string is


`jdbc:teradata://99.99.99.99/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8,TYPE=FASTLOADCSV,LOG=INFO,SESSIONS=1`

you can set these options when executing a FASTLOAD script as shown here:-


`By default the Tenacity feature is not turned on. The feature is turned on by the script command:
Tenacity n;`

Where n specifies the number of hours FastLoad continues trying to logon. The n specification must be greater than zero. If zero is entered, Teradata FastLoad responds with an error message and terminates. During the Tenacity duration, FastLoad tries to log on every 6 minutes by default. The 6 minute default can be changed by using the script command:
Sleep m;

Where m specifies the number of minutes Teradata FastLoad sleeps before retrying the logon operation. The m specification must be greater than zero. If zero is entered, Teradata FastLoad responds with an error message, and terminates.

Below is an example of Tenacity usage. Suppose the commands in the script are:
Tenacity 1;

Sleep 15;

The Tenacity duration is 60 minutes and the Sleep interval is 15 minutes.


can these option sbe set when performing FASTLOADCSV via jdbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think those options exist because FASTLOADCSV is not the same as a FastLoad, it's just using the low level FastLoad *protocol*.

You probably have to implement the sleep and tenacity logic within your program, checking for a 2633(?) error when you connect.

Comment: thats what i was worried about. we see; Throwable occurred: com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.21] [Error 1384] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while in
itializing FastLoad then we get [Error 1383] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the
exception chain occurred while creating FastLoad resources for destination database table. Found 882 AMP(s) and created 0 Connection(s) and 0 PreparedStatement(s) with
SESSIONS=1, but all FastLoad resources that were created have now been closed.

Comment: then we receive; [Error 2633] [SQLState HY000] Too many load/unload tasks running: try again later